# Argparse to match the first option entry only

Tags: python, argparse

I have a problem when using argparse in one of the corner cases. Say, I have a script that runs another application in a following manner:

```
./myScript -a 1 -b 2 -c 3 <etc> ./application.exe <application arguments>
```

I don't know and don't care about the arguments of the application, but the problem is that they can conflict with the arguments of the script, e.g. "-abc 123" or even "-a bla_bla". 
What I want is to make argparse to match the first matching option in the command line and doesn't try matching the rest of the string. Is it possible?

Eg:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument('-a', '--aaa', default=1, dest='first_entry') 
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args() 
print args
```

produces the following output for `./example.py -a 3 someApplication -ab 4`:

```
Namespace(first_entry='b')
```

while I would like it to be

```
Namespace(first_entry='3')
```

In my exact case the launch string looks the following way

```
`./script -a 1 -b1 2 -b2 2 -b3 2 ... -bX 2 -c 3 ./application.exe -ab 3`
```

where `-a, -b1, .., -bX, -c` can be placed in any order
I cannot add all possible arguments into my script, as basically I would like to check only -a and -c and pass everything else to another script (with huge amount of supported options).
When I am using `REMAINDER` it places everything after `-a` option into the `rest`, while I would like to get `-c` value also.

Comment: Can you change `-a` so it does not conflict with other arguments?  `--a` might even work, better yet `--anything-but-ab`.  `--` options are handle differently from `-` ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the positional arguments to take the *remainder* of the command line:

```
parser.add_argument('command', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
```

This tells `argparse` to swallow all arguments into the `command` variable on the namespace, once positional arguments are being parsed:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
>>> parser.add_argument('-a', '--aaa', default=1, dest='first_entry') 
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-a', '--aaa'], dest='first_entry', nargs=None, const=None, default=1, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('command', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='command', nargs='...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['-a', '3', 'someApplication', '-ab', '4'])
Namespace(command=['someApplication', '-ab', '4'], first_entry='3')
```

From the [`nargs` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> `argparse.REMAINDER`. All the remaining command-line arguments are gathered into a list. This is commonly useful for command line utilities that dispatch to other command line utilities:

You cannot really do what you actually want; cherry pick out arbitrary arguments in arbitrary ordering. You can capture specific arguments before the `command` part and arbitrary arguments after, but supporting arbitrary arguments before the `command` part too is unworkable because you cannot know what optional arguments take parameters and which ones don't. `argparse` cannot help you here.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I cannot change the format of command line. There is no "--" allowed.

Comment: Probably, there is at least a way to make argparse to do exact match, so that --foo won't match with --food?

Comment: Argparse never matches `--food` against a configured option named `--foo`. I'm not sure what you are asking here; do you need to validate the options captured by the `argparse.REMAINDER` option too?

Comment: Well, very simple script:

    `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--aaa', default=1, dest='first_entry')
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args() 
    print args`

The output for `./example.py -a bla someApplication -ab 4` is the following:
    Namespace(first_entry='b')

Comment: @YuliaSh.: you forgot to show what command-line arguments you used. But you are referring to the [abbreviation support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching); I don't think that that can be disabled.

Comment: @YuliaSh.: looks like it'll be possible in Python 3.5, which has a new `allow_abbrev` switch (default set to `True`). See https://bugs.python.org/issue14910.

Comment: I've added the code sample into the question body. Basically, Python match the latest entry of the option (and even not exactly the same option, as my example shows)

Comment: @YuliaSh.: I've updated my demo in return; `argparse.REMAINDER` solves this perfectly still.

Comment: Yes, I tried your approach, but it is tricky in my situation. The launch string looks the following way
`./script -a 1 -b1 2 -b2 2 -b3 2 ... -bX 2 -c 3 ./application.exe -ab 3`
where `-a, -b1, .., -bX, -c` can be placed in any order
I cannot add all possible arguments into my script, as basically I would like to check only -a and -c and pass everything else to another script (with huge amount of supported options).
When I am using `REMAINDER` it places everything after `-a` option into the `rest`, while I would like to get `-c` value also.

Comment: @YuliaSh.: You are no longer talking edge-cases here. You are now adding unknown options into the mix, complicating matters. That's a whole different question from the one you posted.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I really appreciate your answers there (and up-voted it). I'll add this info into original question.

Comment: @YuliaSh.: what you want (only define a few optional arguments that can be used before the `command` part) cannot be done with argparse, as far as I can see. There is just no way to properly parse those arguments and still know what is a parameter that goes with a `-` or `--` optional argument and what is something else.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! After all, I had to implement what I needed by myself without using argpase.